# Python remove specific adjacent duplicates from list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, duplicates

```
I have a list 

x=['b1','00','00','10','10','F5','D1','01','01'...]  # sample data
```

I am trying to remove duplicates of '10' only when they are adjacent.

Till now I have tried

```
my_list= [x[i] for i in range(len(x)) if (i==0) or ( x[i] !=x[i-1])] # current implementation
```

This removes  all adjacent duplicates but I want to keep '00','00' and '01' and just remove duplicates of '10'

How do I achieve this using a list comprehension?

Comment: Why does it *have* to use a list comp?

Comment: @PM2Ring homework, presumably

Comment: Just add an extra condition - `or (x[i] != '10')`

Comment: @ andrew_reece It worked !

Comment: @Poka great - just moved my comment into an answer, please mark accepted if your problem is resolved.

Comment: @ andrew_reece I have one more issue. In case I have '10','10','10','10' . When even number of '10' is repeating and I want to retain half of that. How to retain two 10 i.e '10','10' instead of 4 '10'. Is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an extra condition to your list comprehension: `or (x[i] != '10')`.

```
[x[i] for i in range(len(x)) if (i==0) or (x[i] !=x[i-1]) or (x[i] != '10')]
# ['b1', '00', '00', '10', 'F5', 'D1', '01', '01']
```